# How to prove this identity involving dot product of solid angle and gradient

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, solid-angle

How to prove following for $n\geq0$.
$$\int_{4\pi}d\vec{\Omega}(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\vec{\nabla})^{2n}f(\vec{r})=\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}\nabla^{2n}f(\vec{r})$$
Where, at any point $\vec{r}$, the $\vec{\Omega}$ can be described by the polar angle $\theta$ measured with respect to the *z* axis and an azimuthal angle $\phi$ measured with respect to the *x* axis, *i.e.*
$\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$,
$\cos\theta=\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{k}$,
$\cos\phi=sin^{-1}\theta(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{i})$
Here, $\vec{\Omega}$ is a unit vector situated at $\vec{r}$ and pointing in the direction ($\theta,\phi$) which is different than the direction of $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question was now asked also on MathOverflow: [Identity involving dot product of solid angle and gradient](https://mathoverflow.net/q/327960). (Although the MO copy have [received some close votes](https://mathoverflow.net/review/close/113083).)

Comment: It is [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327963/138233) there by [@CarloBeenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker). It was posted there after it did not receive any answer here. Kindly suggest if it is needed to be removed from here.